# intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2 driver

Tags: drivers, video, intel

HD videos in Youtube doesn't run good on my Lenovo S10e Laptop.
If someone can bring me a full guide of installing which is clear, I'll appreciate it much.
I've tried one site but it was to complicated to me. Please help!

Thank You!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

just upgrade your PC... those drivers are present on the kernel....

visit system info from dash and visit the graphics section see to it that the expierence is standard and not fail safe

i had the same issue it wont detect my video driver but a few days later it automatically detectd and said Ironfield

Comment: my one isn't installed through the additional driver, i just use my laptop. i paid attention that i have only one resulotion to chice and videos in the internet don't run smoothly. i found a site through intel called 'intellinuxgraphics' but way of installing was too complicated. is there any way to update my driver?

Comment: nopes just wait it takes time but gets detected

Comment: It doesn't take *time* as it's not Magic, Upgrade the kernel if the Chipset isn't detected, it **should** work, my netbook uses an Intel 3000 chipset or as it shows it Intel N10 which is basically a rebranded i945G and HD videos just don't work, also upgrade your browser and flash version, the chipset just doesn't live up to the task, no matter what you may think.

Comment: How much time would you say?                                        and if driver detected automatically so what this site for? http://intellinuxgraphics.org/ i thought of using it but i couldn't understand it.

Comment: can i unstall more than two kind of drivers throw the Adittional drivers? because i see only driver for my wireless. can i tell it to show me drivers for my graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package/125197#125197). This graphics chipset is pretty weak, so don't expect too much of it. Also, please be aware that this steps can destroy a functioning System. Hope this helps...